# tkinter and pip in general are almost completely broken for me, what's wrong with it?

Tags: python, tkinter

tkinter and just pip in general, is broken. The label, iconphoto and background tags are all broken, how should i fix this?

```
import tkinter as tk
import random as r

GAME_WIDTH = 700
GAME_HEIGHT = 700
SPEED = 50
SPACE_SIZE = 50
BODY_PARTS = 3
SNAKE_COLOR = "#00FF00"
FOOD_COLOR = "#FF0000"
BACKGROUND_COLOR = "#000000"

class snake:
    pass

class food:
    pass

def next_turn():
    pass

def change_directions(new_direction):
    pass

def check_collison():
    pass

def game_over():
    pass


window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Snake game")
window.resizable(False, False)

score = 0
direction = 'down'

label = tk.Label(window, text="Score:{}".format(score), font=('consolas', 40))
label.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

when i run this code, all it gives me is a blank tk window
edit:
even with the "()" tkinter doesnt work

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.geometry("420x420")
window.title("Meow")
window.mainloop()
emoji5 = PhotoImage(file="logo.png")
window.iconphoto(False,emoji5)
window.config(background="#000000")
```

this also gives me a blank GUI, i cant edit anything for some reason, the title works, but nothing else
edit 2:
thanks its solved now i was just stupid lole

Comment: A blank Tk window is all you've created here.  The Label won't become visible until you call some geometry management method on it, such as `.pack()`.  Merely mentioning the *name* of a method doesn't call it.

Comment: Looks like you're missing "()" on label.pack. Add that and it should fix your issue. You need to pack() or grid() all your labels, buttons, etc. for them to be added to the window.

Comment: At the time that I write this, the first block of code creates a window that shows "Score: 0" in a largish font.

Comment: You mention pip. What does this question have to do with pip? You can't install tkinter with pip.

Comment: Are you running on OSX?

Comment: Your second example has all of the supposedly non-working code *after* the call to `mainloop()` - which doesn't exit until the window is closed, so none of the following code is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the bottom block of code, the call to `window.mainloop()` won't return until after the main window has been destroyed. That is how it is designed to work.

Before that point, you haven't done anything to affect the window other than set the title and size.

In short, you need to have created your widgets before calling `mainloop`.